# Show paused Timer value in Label

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I've created a C# windows form application that uses a timer to clear the input boxes every 5 minutes. There is a label called lblTime that displays the amount of time elapsed at any given point while the application is open.
I would like to be able to disable or pause the Timer (Clock.Enabled = false) with a button click, and have lblTime stay on the amount of time elapsed when the button was clicked. However, due to the way that the elapsedTime variable is calculated (DateTime.Now - startTime), this value carries on changing even after the timer has been disabled.

So, to sum up:
lblTime displays running time as Clock ticks
Clock can be disabled by button click, but lblTime carries on incrementing
lblTime needs to stop on current value on same button click that disables Clock, and then be able to start counting again from that same value.

Code that starts Clock, initialises and updates lblTime is displayed.

Any help would this would be very much appreciated,
Thanks,
Mark

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Timers set to start ticking
        Clock.Enabled = true;
        startTime = DateTime.Now; //the milisecond that btnStart is clicked
        initialiseClock();
        initialiseIntervalCounter();
    }

    private void initialiseClock() //initialisation of Clock Timer
    {
        Clock = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        Clock.Tick += new EventHandler(Clock_Tick); //calls Clock EventHandler
        Clock.Interval = 1000; //1 second in miliseconds
        Clock.Start();
    }

    private void Clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //Clock EventHandler definition
    {
        updateTimeDisplay();
        checkDisplay();
    }

    private void updateTimeDisplay()
    {
        elapsedTime = (DateTime.Now - startTime);
        lblTime.Text = Convert.ToString(elapsedTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `bool` flag and a `TimeSpan` and a counter for the seconds until the next clearing:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan elapsed = new TimeSpan(0);
bool running = true;
int clearInSeconds = 300;

private void Clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // function one: count elapsed running time
    if (running) elapsed = elapsed.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
    lblTime.Text = startTime.Add(elapsed).ToLongTimeString();
    // function two: clear stuff after interval:
    if (clearInSeconds-- <= 0)
    {
        clearInSeconds = 300;
        // clear your stuff now
    }
}
```

Use your button click to switch between running and not running. I used a click on the label:

```
private void lblTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    running = !running;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the method in which the countdown time is used.  Use a TimeSpan datatype.  Initialize the variable to 5 minutes `New TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)` and use it instead of a start time and Now().